# timer doesn't stop c#

Tags: c#, timer

I am using timer in form to send a command to a controller after every 3 seconds when user presses button. The timer should stop after user again presses same button. But in my case timer doesn't stop. I am using timer in the following way.

```
private void autoModeTempBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tempTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
        tempTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
        tempTimer.AutoReset = true;

        if (autoModeTempBtn.Text == "Get Temperature Auto Mode")
        {
            autoModeTempBtn.Text = "hello";

            tempTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnTemperatureEvent);
            tempTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else /*user presses button second time */
        {
            tempTimer.Stop();
            tempTimer.AutoReset = false;
            tempTimer.Enabled = false;
            autoModeTempBtn.Text = "Get Temperature Auto Mode";
        }
    }
    private void OnTemperatureEvent(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

Where I am making mistake?

Comment: You cannot possibly stop the timer, you can't get a reference to the timer object since it is a local variable of your Click event handler.  So it just keeps on ticking, ticking.  Make it a field of your class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating your timer new every time you click the button. Create the timer once and just Start/Stop it everytime you click. Also you should use the [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead of the `System.Timers.Timer`.

```
var _timer = new Timer() { Interval = 3000 };

private void autoModeTempBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!validateSerialNumber())
        return;

    if (!_timer.Enabled)
    {
        _timer.Start();
        autoModeTempBtn.Text = "hello";
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        autoModeTempBtn.Text = "Get Temperature Auto Mode";
    }
}
```

And add this code to your constructor:

```
_timer.Tick += OnTemperatureEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, using Windows.Forms.Timer instead of Timers.Timer solved my problem.